# python Unitest sample Application

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am facing problem in Python Unittesting,

simple Addition of two numbers in python Unitest, for different test case ID or Different Inputs.

-------Prasanna Yelsangikar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import unittest

class UnitTestExamples(unittest.TestCase):

    def testsum(self):
        a = 10
        b = 42
        self.assertEqual(a+b,52)

if __name__  == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Run the above in with your python interpretor using -v flag.

```
python testexample.py -v
```

And you will see that testsum is run and the test is exercised. [unittest](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) documentation has details how the working and the above example should be simple enough to get you started. The methods which start with the name test are run by the unittest framework.

Comment: thanks, How can I give different Input values for a and b in console without writing values in python file...

Comment: You cannot pass the commandline args to the unittest framework because it has it's validation of what kind of args that it can take. Usually, for 'unit testing' those values and combinations are predefined and they are given in the code itself. Perhaps you might just want to use assert statements for what you are trying. Or there could be some other framework which take take a option from the command line arg.

Comment: ok fine, here in this example a=10,b=42 but i want to give values a and b with different values for a and b is it possible to give in above example...

Comment: How to Run above example without this statement in a alternatively : if __name__  == '__main__':
    unittest.main()  , please post the answer.....

Comment: No, you cannot do that. unittest is a framework which requires it to call its execution methods. Alternatively, you can install www.pytest.org and have them without that name.

Answer (score 0):

#test_numbers.py is located at 'tests' folder

```
import unittest 
class testNumbers(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add_two_numbers(self):
    
        first_number = 3
        second_number = 7


        result = first_number + second_number 
        expected = 10


        self.assertEqual(result,expected)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(testNumbers)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
```

**run on terminal :**

```
python -m tests.test_numbers
```